# How can I add cooldown to my discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to add cooldown to /chat command. How can I do that? Since I pull the data from ChatGPT, I can have a rate limit on spam usage. To solve this I need to add time per user.

```
 @client.tree.command(name="chat", description="Have a chat with ChatGPT")
    async def chat(interaction: discord.Interaction, *, message: str):
        if interaction.user == client.user:
            return
        username = str(interaction.user)
        user_message = message
        channel = str(interaction.channel)
        logger.info(
            f"\x1b[31m{username}\x1b[0m : '{user_message}' ({channel})")
        await send_message(interaction, user_message)
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `commands.cooldown` decorator  to do just that:

```
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def chat(...):
 ...
```

this would allow each user 1 `chat` command per 30 seconds. You can also do it at a server level with `BucketType.server` instead.